# JTable to iReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, pdf-generation, ireport

I'm trying to get the data that I have in a JTable and print it like a report using Jasper Reports. I've found [Usando o JRBeanCollectionDataSource](http://www.furutani.com.br/2009/02/usando-o-jrbeancollectiondatasource/) and [Java beans as Jasper Reports data source using JRBeanCollectionDataSource](http://www.robertomarchetto.com/www/how_to_print_java_collections_in_jasper_reports_using_JRBeanCollectionDataSource) as examples to create my own code:

```
package Negocio.Relatorios;

import Negocio.Contato;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer;

public class DataFromRelatorios{

    public void exibirRelatorio(List<Contato> contatos){

        String caminhoJasper = "./etiquetas.jasper";
        JRBeanCollectionDataSource dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(contatos);
        Map parameters = new HashMap();
        JasperPrint printer;
        InputStream relJas = getClass().getResourceAsStream(caminhoJasper);

        try {
            printer = JasperFillManager.fillReport(relJas, parameters, dataSource);
            JasperViewer viewer = new JasperViewer(printer, true);
            viewer.setVisible(true);
        }
        catch (JRException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }
}
```

This class is called when the ActionEvent occurs:

```
private void btnGeraEtiquetasActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
        geradorRelatorios.exibirRelatorio(relatorioTableModel.getDados());
    }
```

This is my trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.<clinit>(JRLoader.java:65)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRPropertiesUtil.loadProperties(JRPropertiesUtil.java:99)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.DefaultJasperReportsContext.initProperties(DefaultJasperReportsContext.java:95)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.DefaultJasperReportsContext.<init>(DefaultJasperReportsContext.java:72)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.DefaultJasperReportsContext.<clinit>(DefaultJasperReportsContext.java:60)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.getDefaultInstance(JasperFillManager.java:85)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:956)
    at Negocio.Relatorios.DataFromRelatorios.exibirRelatorio(DataFromRelatorios.java:25)
    at GUI.JanGerenciaContato.btnGeraEtiquetasActionPerformed(JanGerenciaContato.java:239)
    at GUI.JanGerenciaContato.access$300(JanGerenciaContato.java:21)
    at GUI.JanGerenciaContato$4.actionPerformed(JanGerenciaContato.java:104)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6288)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6053)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4651)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:643)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:602)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:600)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:616)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:614)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:613)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 47 more
```

I thought I had all the necessary libraries for Jasper Reports, which one am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you are missing the [Jakarta Commons Logging Component (version 1.0.4 or later)](http://jakarta.apache.org/commons/logging/) library on your classpath. You should probably take a look at the [JasperReports Requirements](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/requirements.html) to make sure you have all the other required libraries you need and the appropriate versions.

As an aside, you mentioned you data is in a JTable, you may want to take a look at [JRTableModelDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRTableModelDataSource.html) which will let you us the Jtable's TableModel to create a datasource.

Comment: Hello, i've added all jars metioned here > http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/requirements.html but when i run it i got a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError then i saw the path and it is: "org/apache/commons/digester/Rule", but my package looks like: "org.commons.digester3.xmlrule", it's a version problem?
And at this page > http://commons.apache.org/digester/download_digester.cgi i found only these download links.

Comment: My guess is you are not using the latest version of the other related libraries, or of jasper reports itself. My recomendaton, is deleted all those libraries you currently have, and start over. Get the latest version of jasper reports and the latest versions of the libraries listed in the Jasper Reports requirements.